# remove index.php in codeigniter with wamp not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I am facing problem while removing index.php from url in Codeigniter 3 using Wamp Server. I was changes in file config.php (project_folder/application/config/config.php)

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

and create .htaccess file same level of application folder with code written

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|opensearch\.xml|favicon\.ico|assets|forums)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

and rewrite_module is on and my virtual host code is

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "D:/work/project_Name/" 
    ServerName abc.local 
    <Directory "D:/work/project_Name/"> 
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

using these changes and code my project not run without index.php and error throw

```
abc.local/controllername
Not found
The requested URL /controllername/ was not found on this server.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read   this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/

Comment: the above said problem has solved by change in virtual host file httpd-vhosts.conf ( C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra ).By replacing "Order Allow,Deny" into "Allow from all" Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And on `config.php` page set `$config['base_url'] ="http://localhost/project/"` and `$config['index_page'] = '';` and `$config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';`

Comment: click on Wampserver and select apache->httpd.conf and remove # from #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. Finally Restart Wamp Server

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folder_name_of_project/


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```